# Iteration over a non-existing file in the directory

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have around five files in my directory that I want to read in r. Each file has a name pattern: "filex.html", where x=1,2,3 and so on. However, a few files are missing. I wanted to create a loop to read all the files and whenever any file is non-existential, the loop should jump to next file in the sequence. However, my loop stops whenever it encounters the first non-existing file.

Following is the loop.

```
ids = c(1:10)

for (i in ids) {
  myurl = paste("mypage",i,".html") 
  myurl = gsub(" ","",myurl)
  pointer = read_html(myurl)
   if(is_null(pointer)){
     next
   }
    
    
}
```

This is the error.

```
Error: 'mypage3.html' does not exist in current working directory ('E:/My_projects/mydb').
```

How can iterate my loop over the non-existing file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over your `ids` vector that may include non-existant files, try to `lapply` over a list of the actual files, obtained from `list.files()`.

You can use a pattern to only get the `html` files with `list.files(pattern = "*.html")`.

Here is an example

```r
html_files = list.files(pattern = "*.html").

lapply(html_files, function(x) {
    pointer = read_html(x)
}
```

Comment: Will it also work if I want to download HTML files from respective URLs first?

Comment: This will make a list of all the HTML files in your working directory, which you will then loop over. You can use this with any functions inside the `lapply` statement.